# Word order for modal verbs in the passive, in a subordinate clause

Tags: word-order, modal-verb, subordinate-clause, passive, verbal-complex

I have the sentence:

> To prevent infections in the first instance, so that antibiotics do not have to be used.

and I've translated it to:

> Infektionen überhaupt vorzubeugen, sodass Antibiotika nicht benutzt werden müssen.

Is the word order for the last three verbs correct? I'm not sure if *werden* must be before *müssen*, before *benutzt*, or at the end.

Comment: Your translation attempt is indeed correct, if the english said *do not need to be used*. Otherwise, it would be *dürfen*.

Comment: @Janka "Do not need to be used" and "do not have to be used" are effectively the same, so the translation is correct for either case.

Comment: By the way, I'd translate *in the first instance* more narrowly, either *sofort*, or word for word *an erster Stelle*, *in erster Instanz*, *als erstes*, *von Anfang an*, because *überhaupt* would idiomatically go in the second part with *gar nicht erst*, "damit Anitbiotika *überhaupt gar nicht erst* eingesetzt werden müssen", which is in a colloquial register though. I would not capitalize start of the sentence, because lacking a subject, it is not really a full sentence, and there's no main clause finite verb, only a zu-infinitive and the infinitive *müssen*. It's Odd in the original too.

Answer (score 1):

The simple rule for verb placement is, when you make a subordinate clause from a main clause, the finite verb moves to the end. Same for the modals, as soon a modal is involved, the finite verb becomes an infinitive and moves to the end. So,

> Es **wird** benutzt. → …, so dass es benutzt **wird.**
>
> Es **muss** benutzt werden. → …, so dass es benutzt werden **muss**.

But take care, as soon the row of infinitives and participles gets longer, the finite verb **typically** leads it:

> Es **hat** benutzt werden müssen. → …, so dass es **hat** benutzt werden müssen.

This exception is strong for *haben*, less so for other verbs. They are okay with both options:

> Es **wird** benutzt werden müssen. → …, so dass es **wird** benutzt werden müssen.
>
> Es **wird** benutzt werden müssen. → …, so dass es benutzt werden müssen **wird**.
>
> Es **sollte** benutzt werden müssen. → …, so dass es **sollte** benutzt werden müssen.
>
> Es **sollte** benutzt werden müssen. → …, so dass es benutzt werden müssen **sollte**.